# ArcGIS Android syncing geodatabase does not work after downloading it with LayerQueries

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, query, android, arcgis-android

I need to download a geodatabase from ArcGIS server using layer IDs and LayerQueries in database parameter class and then be able to sync both ways.

The ArcGIS Android API examples are only based on downloading the whole geodatabase using FeatureServiceInfo which is not feasible in my case (I can't think of any other logical use anyway).

Below code is my Geodatabase Utility class. Download works just fine with the `WHERE` queries I set. The only problem is the sync part.

The logcat output from the syncing process responds with no errors.
The way I check the content of my database is using the property `gdbFeatureTableInfo` in my class which fills up in the method `postGdbTaskComplete`, which gets called in both callbacks of creating a geodatabase or syncing the existing one.

```
public class GeodatabaseUtility {
    private Activity activity;
    private MapView mapView;
    private String gdbDataSDCardDirName;
    private String gdbFileName;
    private String gdbFilePath;
    private String gdbServiceURL;
    private File gdbDataFile;
    private int[] selectedLayers;
    private String OFFLINE_FILE_EXTENSION;
    private GenerateGeodatabaseParameters gdbParams;
    private SyncGeodatabaseParameters gdbSyncParams;
    private GeodatabaseSyncTask gdbSyncTask;
    private LayerQueries gdbLayerQueries;       // holds a number of LayerQuery items
    private ProgressDialog downloadGeodatabseDialog;
    private ProgressDialog syncGeodatabseDialog;
    private String gdbFeatureTableInfo;
    private FeatureServiceInfo gdbFeatureServiceInfo;
    GeodatabaseStatusCallback gdbStatusCallback;
    private ApplicationSharedSingleton A;

    public GeodatabaseUtility(MapView mapView, String gdbFileName, String gdbDataSDCardDirName, String serviceURL, Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mapView = mapView;
        gdbDataFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        OFFLINE_FILE_EXTENSION = activity.getString(R.string.map_fragment_config_geodatabase_file_extention);
        this.gdbDataSDCardDirName = gdbDataSDCardDirName;
        this.gdbFileName = gdbFileName;
        this.gdbServiceURL = serviceURL;
        this.gdbFilePath = createGeodatabaseFilePath();
        this.gdbLayerQueries = new LayerQueries();
        this.gdbSyncTask = new GeodatabaseSyncTask(this.gdbServiceURL, null);   //user credentials here
        // a callback which updates when the status of the task changes
        gdbStatusCallback = new GeodatabaseStatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void statusUpdated(GeodatabaseStatusInfo status) {
                Log.i(MapFragment.TAG, status.getStatus().toString());
            }
        };
        A = ApplicationSharedSingleton.getInstance();
    }

    //returns a single query to be added to LayerQueries
    public void GenQueryToSelectFeaturesFromLayerID(int layerID){
        LayerQuery q = LayerQuery.createUsingFilter(layerID,"ID='7'",true);
        this.gdbLayerQueries.add(q);
    }

    public void StartGeodatabase(){
        // if geodatabase exists, synchronize it
        File elif = new File(this.gdbFilePath);
        if(elif.exists()) {
            syncGeodatabase();
            //new RecreateGeodatabase().execute();
        }
        // else create a new geodatabase
        else
            createGeodatabase();

    }

    private class RecreateGeodatabase extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                A.setLocalGdb(new Geodatabase(gdbFilePath));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            A.getLocalGdb().dispose();
            deleteRecursive(new File(gdbDataFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + gdbDataSDCardDirName));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            createGeodatabase();
        }
    }

    private void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
                deleteRecursive(child);
        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }

   /* we are not using this code yet, since the server sync through geodatabase is not possible
    instead, the geodatabase will be destroyed and recreated, sync process will be done manually
    on the ArcGISFeatureLayer instead if FeatureLayer*/
    private void syncGeodatabase(){
        CallbackListener<GeodatabaseStatusInfo> gdbStatusInfoCallback = new CallbackListener<GeodatabaseStatusInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(GeodatabaseStatusInfo geodatabaseStatusInfo) {}
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {}
        };
        syncGeodatabseDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mapView.getContext(), "Gdb already exists", "syncing...");
        try {
            A.setLocalGdb(new Geodatabase(gdbFilePath));
            try {
                gdbSyncTask.registerGeodatabase(A.getLocalGdb(),gdbStatusCallback, gdbStatusInfoCallback);
                gdbSyncParams = A.getLocalGdb().getSyncParameters();
                    /*LayerSyncInfos linfos = new LayerSyncInfos();
                    LayerSyncInfo linfo = new LayerSyncInfo();
                    linfo.setLayerId(0);
                    linfos.add(linfo);
                    gdbSyncParams.setSyncLayers(linfos);*/
                //gdbSyncParams.setSyncDirection(SyncDirection.DOWNLOAD);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CallbackListener<Map<Integer, GeodatabaseFeatureTableEditErrors>> syncResponseCallback = new CallbackListener<Map<Integer, GeodatabaseFeatureTableEditErrors>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(Map<Integer, GeodatabaseFeatureTableEditErrors> objs) {
                syncGeodatabseDialog.dismiss();
                if (objs != null) {
                    if (objs.size() > 0) {
                        Log.e(MapFragment.TAG,"there are errors");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(MapFragment.TAG,"Sync Completed Without Errors");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(MapFragment.TAG,"Sync Completed Without Errors");
                }
                postGdbTaskComplete(gdbFilePath);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                syncGeodatabseDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e(MapFragment.TAG, "", e);
                ShowDialog(e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        gdbSyncTask.syncGeodatabase(gdbSyncParams,A.getLocalGdb(),
                gdbStatusCallback,syncResponseCallback);
    }



    private void createGeodatabase(){
        downloadGeodatabseDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mapView.getContext(), "Veritabani", "Create local runtime geodatabase");
        CallbackListener<String> gdbResponseCallback = new CallbackListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable e) {
                Log.e(MapFragment.TAG, e.getMessage());
                downloadGeodatabseDialog.dismiss();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String path) {
                Log.i(MapFragment.TAG, "Geodatabase is: " + path);
                downloadGeodatabseDialog.dismiss();
                // update map with local feature layer from geodatabase
                postGdbTaskComplete(path);      // what to do when gdb is created successfully
            }
        };
        gdbParams = new GenerateGeodatabaseParameters(selectedLayers,gdbLayerQueries,mapView.getExtent(),
                mapView.getSpatialReference(),true, SyncModel.GEODATABASE,mapView.getSpatialReference());
        gdbSyncTask.generateGeodatabase(gdbParams, gdbFilePath, false, gdbStatusCallback, gdbResponseCallback);
    }

    private void createGeodatabaseFromFeatureServiceInfo(){
        this.gdbSyncTask.fetchFeatureServiceInfo(new CallbackListener<FeatureServiceInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(MapFragment.TAG, "", e);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCallback(FeatureServiceInfo objs) {
                if (objs.isSyncEnabled()) {
                    Log.e(MapFragment.TAG,"sync is enabled");
                }
            }
        });
        CallbackListener<String> gdbResponseCallback = new CallbackListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable e) {
                Log.e(MapFragment.TAG, e.getMessage());
                downloadGeodatabseDialog.dismiss();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String path) {
                Log.i(MapFragment.TAG, "Geodatabase is: " + path);
                downloadGeodatabseDialog.dismiss();
                // update map with local feature layer from geodatabase
                postGdbTaskComplete(path);      // what to do when gdb is created successfully
            }
        };
    }



    private void postGdbTaskComplete(String gdbFilePath) {
        if(A.getLocalGdb() == null) {
            try {
                A.setLocalGdb(new Geodatabase(gdbFilePath));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // create info
        gdbFeatureTableInfo = "";
        if (A.getLocalGdb() != null) {
            for (GeodatabaseFeatureTable gdbFeatureTable : A.getLocalGdb().getGeodatabaseTables()) {
                gdbFeatureTableInfo+=gdbFeatureTable.getTableName().toString()+"   "
                        +String.valueOf(gdbFeatureTable.getNumberOfFeatures())+" \n";
            }
            // addlayers TODO: need to check if layers already exist, and the add
            addGeodatabaseFeatureLayers();
        }
    }

    private String createGeodatabaseFilePath() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(gdbDataFile.getAbsolutePath());
        sb.append(File.separator);
        sb.append(gdbDataSDCardDirName);
        sb.append(File.separator);
        sb.append(gdbFileName);
        sb.append(OFFLINE_FILE_EXTENSION);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void addGeodatabaseFeatureLayers(){
        if (A.getLocalGdb() != null) {
            for (GeodatabaseFeatureTable gdbFeatureTable : A.getLocalGdb().getGeodatabaseTables()) {
                if(gdbFeatureTable.hasGeometry())
                    mapView.addLayer(new FeatureLayer(gdbFeatureTable));
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowDialog(String msg){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder1.setMessage(msg);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
    }

    public int[] getSelectedLayers() {
        return selectedLayers;
    }

    public void setSelectedLayers(int[] selectedLayers) {
        this.selectedLayers = selectedLayers;
    }

    public String getGdbFeatureTableInfo() {
        return gdbFeatureTableInfo;
    }

    public void setGdbFeatureTableInfo(String gdbFeatureTableInfo) {
        this.gdbFeatureTableInfo = gdbFeatureTableInfo;
    }




}
```

and the way I use it is the following:

```
gdbUtil = new GeodatabaseUtility(mMapView,
                    this.getResources().getString(R.string.map_fragment_config_geodatabase_name),
                    this.getResources().getString(R.string.map_fragment_config_data_sdcard_offline_dir),
                    getString(R.string.map_fragment_feature_service_url),getActivity());
            int[] ids = {0,1,2,3,4};
            gdbUtil.setSelectedLayers(ids);
            gdbUtil.GenQueryToSelectFeaturesFromLayerID(0);         //TODO:under construction method
            gdbUtil.StartGeodatabase();
```